# jQuery validate group 3 text inputs into one?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I have 3 text inputs for a phone number - phone_ac, phone_ex, phone_nm - i.e. 999 555 1212

I can use jquery to validate each individually and give 3 error messages:

```
"Phone number (area code) is required."
"Phone number (exchange) is required."
"Phone number (last 4 digits) is required."
```

Is there a way to have one error message only if ANY of the 3 fields are blank?

Answer (score 0):

I've previously handled similar situations by adding a hidden input named PhoneNumber and adding required and regex validation flags on it.  Then prior to validating the form set its value to the concatenation of all three fields.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 0):

Set an errorContainer option with element that contains common error message and errorLabelContainer option and wrap the errorLabelContainer by unvisible container element.

```
   <style type="text/css">
       #errorMessage
       {
           display: none;
       }
   </style>

    <div style="display: none;">
        <div id="errorLabels" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="phone_ac" class="required"  />
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="phone_ex" class="required" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="phone_nm" class="required" />
    <div id="errorMessage">
        All phone fields are required!</div>
    <hr />
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#stay-in-touch').validate({

                highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
                    $('#span1').text("Please enter all the values");
                },
                rules: {
                    text1: "required",
                    text2: "required",
                    text3: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    text1: "",
                    text2: "",
                    text3: ""
                }
            });
        });


    </script>


    <form method="post" action="Default2.aspx" id="stay-in-touch" >
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" /> <br />              
        <input type="text" id="text2" name="text2" /> <span id="span1"></span> <br />              
        <input type="text" id="text3" name="text3" /> <br />   

        <input type="submit" value="submit" />           

    </div> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in jquery validate called 'groups' that does this. You can include it in your validate and group them by their ID's so if you have:

```
 <div>
    <input type="text" id="phone_ac" name="phone_ac" />              
    <input type="text" id="phone_ex" name="phone_ex" />              
    <input type="text" id="phone_nm" name="phone_nm" />   
</div>
```

Try adding groups to you validate:

```
$('#yourform').validate({
//...Your existing validation logic...
groups: {
    phoneNumbers: "phone_ac phone_ex phone_nm"
}  
});
```